# Constantly Run a Service and check a value of a Variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I had created some code that would tell me if the users window scrolled beyond a certain point. I quickly realised that this needed to be a service as other components needed this info as well.

I had used @HostListener in the logic and would get results. Now that this is all in a service, I only know if the window was scrolled beyond a certain point when I call the service.

The issue is, how do I constantly call the service? The service has a Boolean in it that I need real-time info on.

## Service

```
import { Injectable, OnInit, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class WindowScrollService {
  public navIsFixed: boolean = false;
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

   }
   @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;
    if (number > 20) {
      this.navIsFixed = true;
      console.log(this.navIsFixed);
    } else if (this.navIsFixed && number < 10) {
      this.navIsFixed = false;
      console.log(this.navIsFixed);
    }
  }
}
```

## Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowScrollService } from '../window-scroll.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public navIsFixed: boolean;

  constructor( private windowscrollservice  : WindowScrollService) { 
  this.navIsFixed = this.windowscrollservice.navIsFixed;

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.windowscrollservice.onWindowScroll()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` to repeatedly run some code. One possible implementation

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowScrollService } from '../window-scroll.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public navIsFixed: boolean;
  public interval;

  constructor( private windowscrollservice  : WindowScrollService) { 
  this.navIsFixed = this.windowscrollservice.navIsFixed;

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    // run every 500ms
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.windowscrollservice.onWindowScroll(), 500);
    // use clearInterval(this.interval) to stop
  }
}
```